# What does the && operator do when is it between two strings?

Tags: c, syntax, boolean-logic, and-operator

In the below code what does the statements `str1[i] && str2[i];` and `count1[str1[i]]++;` do exactly ?

```
char str1[4]="rate";
char str2[4]="tear";

int count1[256] ;
int count2[256] ;

int i=0;

for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i];  i++)
{
   count1[str1[i]]++;//count1['g']++what does that mean ?
   count2[str2[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: The latter does seem to be counting the appearance of characters.

Comment: `int count1[256] ;` This will only work when `char` is 8-bit, a common enough assumption, and unsigned, an uncommon one.

Comment: `int str1[]="rate";` does not work. Only a char array can be initialized with a literal string.

Comment: Why don't you read up on the `&&` operator, by the way?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: So it probably should read: `int str1[] = L"rate";`.

Comment: Both `str1` and `str2` are too short: they don't have space for the string `'\0'` terminator. They need to be defined with 5 elements: `char str1[5] = "rate";` or you need to allow the compiler to determine the size: `char str2[] = "tear"; /* compiler uses 5 for array size */`

Comment: @pmg: `int str2[] = L"rate"` would imply a `0` as last (5th) array element.

Comment: @alk: the original code has been changed. But the loop is checking the array elements for zero ...

Comment: Uhm, ok, I see ... so for the current version I do agree. @pmg

Comment: it should read `char *str1 = "rate"` which includes the terminating '\0'. count1[str1[i]] is somewhat dangerous because char is signed and could be negative (not for the characters in this example)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i];  i++)
```

is the same as

```
for (i = 0; (str1[i] != 0) && (str2[i] != 0);  i++)
```

which is the same as

```
for (i = 0; (str1[i] != '\0') && (str2[i] != '\0';  i++)
```

Basically if any expression is used in a conditional statement, then the value is checked for boolean - true or false. If it's not a boolean - say it's an integral type, then 0 is `false` anything else is `true`.

Here `str[i]` is a `char` - which is an integral type. So if str[i] is 0, then it evaluates to false, else it evaluates to true.

For eg.

```
char c = 'A';

if(c)
```

is the same as

```
if (c != 0)
```

which is the same as

```
if (c != '\0')
```

c is 'A' (which in ascii is 65). 65 != 0, hence it evaluates to true & the `if` will be entered.

if instead, you have

```
char c = 0;
```

or

```
char c = '\0';
```

then c evaluates to 0. Hence if(c) evaluates to false & the if is not entered.

You can extend the same logic to str[i] which is an `char`.

If you have `str1[]="rate"`, it's the same as 
`str1[0] = 'r', str1[1] = 'a', str1[2] = 't', str1[3] = 'e', str1[4] = 0`.

About the `count1[str1[i]]++;`

It's a count of how many times each character occurs - for eg. if the char set is ascii, then at the end of string traversal, count['A'] (which is the same as count[65]) will contain the number of times 'A' occurred in the string.

It will work only if each member of the count arrays are initialized to `0` somewhere (or they are global).

consider

```
str1[] = "ABAB";
```

`count[str1[0]]` is same as `count['A']` which is same as `count[65]` (if char set is ascii).

The `++` will cause count['A'] to become 1

When `i` becomes 1, `count[str1[1]]++` causes `count['B']` to become 1.
`i` = 2, then `count['A']` becomes 2.
`i` = 3, then `count['B']` becomes 2.

Comment: The ++ will cause count['A'] or count[65] to become 1.How will it become 1 here ?where will this count value 1 gets stored ? how does increment to 2 next time when the same character('A' ) comes ?

Comment: @krrishna I am assuming each element of count[256] is initialized to 0 somewhere or it's a global. When the first ++ happens, a particular element it becomes 1. When the 2nd ++ happens it becomes 2. When the alphabet is 'A' & the charset is ascii, this happens at count[65] for 'A's and count[66] for 'B's & so on.

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm counts the occurences of each ascii character in two strings simultaneously.

```
str1[i] && str2[i]
```

checks that the end of neither string is reached. `count1[str1[i]]++` increases theo count of  occurence of the character str1[i].

Comment: Does count1[str1[i]]++ increases the count of occurence of the each character str1[i] ? Can you explain how does it increases the count and  stores the count for each character?

Comment: @krrishna - I have added this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The && is applied to 2 characters, not strings.  In this case it is checking that neither character is the null character.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i];  i++)`
Loop runs for number of time smaller string length.
because ASCII value of '\0' is zero (0) , str1[i], or str2[i] zero means and of both zero and loop ends